# Can I use OpenGL for graphics in my C program?

Tags: c, opengl, header-files

I want to use a library for making some shapes in my C program. Can I use `gl.h` in my C program if I install it? Will it be compatible or is it designed for languages other than C?

Comment: Yeah it will work. If you need only basic shapes, it's probably not the simplest solution, though. Take a look at SDL instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally dont *install* gl.h. It is just the header to a library. The **library**-implementation should already be provided by your OS/drivers eg in some .DLL-files. The **header** gl.h can just be #include'ed so you can call the functions.

You did not tell us your OS, but there are tutorials for each, eg for windows: have a look at the tutorials on the right side of http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Comment: Could i please know, which is the best graphics library out there that i can use in my C programs. the best, most advanced, professional library?

Comment: @PranavSharma In general, for PC: if you want your program to run on multiple operating-systems: OpenGL; if Windows-only then OpenGL and DirectX are both fine. (I dont know about non-PC's ie consoles)